# Calendar Image Icon

Tags: swiftui

I would like to set the SWIFT UI calendars looks like the follow image.

[image]

Comment: Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot. SO is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean something like this?

```
HStack(spacing: 50) {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "calendar")
        Text("From")
    }
    
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: "calendar")
        Text("To")
    }
}
```

The code above produces view like this:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you!